# How Share Java Models (with spring annotations) between Client and Server

Tags: java, spring, web-services, model-view-controller, model

I have two java projects using spring, one is the server and the other is the client, both have the models package with practically the same models class. Those model classes are using spring annotations. So can I put those models in a library ? How?

Comment: Put them in a JAR that both client and server share.  Use Maven to manage your dependencies.

Comment: And seriously reconsider sharing actual persistence classes, because that leads to very tight coupling. It's a bit more work but much more flexible to have DTO classes in a shared `api` package and let the server rearrange things however it likes.

Comment: To add to @duffymo's comment, Archiva is a free artifact repository manager that you can use to host your own dependencies. https://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi